# Continuously outputting index of an array

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an array that I want to output each index continuously and randomly
here is my code :

```
package com.example.testtingskripsi;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String [] ArrayA ={"80","81","82","83","84","85"};
    public TextView mViewLabel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int rando =(int) ((Math.random())*ArrayA.length);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textChanger);

        Button startHeartbeat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        Button stopHeartbeat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        startHeartbeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for(int mIfCounter = 0;mIfCounter<ArrayA.length-1;mIfCounter++){
                            mViewLabel.setText(ArrayA[mIfCounter]);
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

the output doesn't change only showing one index and doesn't change to the next index

**edit:**
it does work but on the output, it only shows the last index but still doesn't change

**edit 2:**
Okay so I fixed it with new code and try some of you guys help
this is new code

```
package com.example.testtingskripsi;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String [] ArrayA ={"80","81","82","83","84","85"};
    public TextView mViewLabel;
    boolean continueThread=true;
    int count =0;
    Thread t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textChanger);

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(ArrayA);
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        t = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(continueThread){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if(count<=6){
                                    count++;
                                }else{
                                    count--;
                                }
                                mViewLabel.setText(list.get(count));

                            }
                        });
                    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

    }
    public void BtnStart(View view){
        t.start();;
    }
    public void BtnStop(View view){
        continueThread=false;
    }
}
```

it stop at end of array, so i want it to doing the loop until i pressed stop button any help

Comment: yes because for loop starts every-time from 0, int mIfCounter = 0

Comment: hmm so any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already figured it out so okay thank you all for helling me

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to add some delay inside the for loop.
Try Thread.sleep inside the loop.
The device changes 60 fps so its hard to view the changes for a small loop

Comment: Did you tried runonUIThread inside run function?